# Php cUrl_setopt to Java

Tags: java, php

I have a task that I need to implement a post request from PHP to Java programming language. This is the code segment, what's the equivalent in Java? I don't know the curl_setopt part.

```php
function send()
{
    $fieldcnt    = 6;

    $data = array(
        'UserID' => $this->username,
        'PWD' => $this->password,
        'APIKEY' => $this->apikey,
        'FROM' => $this->from,
        'TO' => $this->to,
        'MSG' => $this->msgtext
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->base_url_SendSMS);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $fieldcnt);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK so first you need to have a Class for Data

```
 public class Data {
            private String UserID;
            private String PWD;
            private String APIKEY;
            private String FROM;
            private String TO;
            private String MSG;
    }
```

Then for each class member you have to generate getters/setters

```
public String getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        UserID = userID;
    }

    public String getPWD() {
        return PWD;
    }

    public void setPWD(String pWD) {
        PWD = pWD;
    }

    public String getAPIKEY() {
        return APIKEY;
    }

    public void setAPIKEY(String aPIKEY) {
        APIKEY = aPIKEY;
    }

    public String getFROM() {
        return FROM;
    }

    public void setFROM(String fROM) {
        FROM = fROM;
    }

    public String getTO() {
        return TO;
    }

    public void setTO(String tO) {
        TO = tO;
    }

    public String getMSG() {
        return MSG;
    }

    public void setMSG(String mSG) {
        MSG = mSG;
    }
```

At this point you are ready to convert your php code

```
$data = array(
        'UserID' => $this->username,
        'PWD' => $this->password,
        'APIKEY' => $this->apikey,
        'FROM' => $this->from,
        'TO' => $this->to,
        'MSG' => $this->msgtext
    );
```

to JAVA.

Lets create your http_build_query

```
Data data = new Data();
        
        data.setUserID("ASDFV238756EW");
        data.setPWD(role);
        data.setAPIKEY("<Your Key>");
```

Now you need to create JSON for your Data Class

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
```

to use curl with Java you need to use Process Builder Package

Note: if you are using Windows you can keep curl.exe but if you are using linux you have to change curl.exe to /usr/bin/curl

```
ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("curl.exe", "[[Your-SMS-Url-Here]]",
                "-X","POST",
                "-H", "Authorization:Bearer <Your Access Token if provided>", 
                "-H", "headers1",
                "-H","headers2",
                "-d",json.toString());
```

So now you are all set with your curl call, just need to add in a process.

```
Process p;
        try {
            p = process.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            /*Set your debug point here, you will see the api response in x vairable below*/
            String x = builder.toString();
            
            try
            {
                
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                if(customer.getDeleted() == true)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                }
                
            }
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In java you might want to use a library like [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html)

Comment: Yes, i know that, but can you help me by "translating" the given code from a programming language to another?